# Error opening device, you don't have permissions (after gammu install)

Tags: gammu

Just after installing the gammu and configuring the **.gammrc** in my home directory (/home/rafael/.gammurc), I get this error and I do not know what file I have to give "sufficient permissions.

```
gammu sendsms TEXT 04165181317 -text "Hallooo.."
```

Error opening device, you don't have permissions

This is my configuration file:

```
rafael@Aspire-one-Lubuntu16:~$ cat .gammurc
[gammu]
port = /dev/ttyUSB0
connection = at    

[gammu1]
port = /dev/ttyUSB1
connection = at

[gammu2]
port = /dev/ttyUSB2
connection = at
```

The  ttyUSB* belongs to group "dialout"

```
rafael@Aspire-one-Lubuntu16:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 ago  8 20:00 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 1 ago  8 18:52 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 2 ago  8 19:19 /dev/ttyUSB2
```

And add my user "rafael to this group:

```
usermod -a -G dialout rafael
```

Any idea to help me???
thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give goods permissions to gammu:

```
chown root:gammu /usr/bin/gammu
usermod -a -G gammu rafael
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem will be solved by the following:
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Allowing full access to all users is seldom a good solution.

Comment: Yes, but it works to solve this issue. You can change the permission based on your network and OS policy.